# SSRS Report Cascade Parameter

Tags: parameters, reporting-services, cascading

Have 3 parameters in my SSRS report, Location, Has book, author

Location will always be selected and is a multivalue drop down and it has it's own dataset.
Has book is a true or false and values come from a dataset as well.
 And author is a drop down with choices which allows multiple values and has its own dataset.

What I need to set is that when false is chosen the author parameter does not need a value and when true is chosen it allows author drop down to be chosen.

Is their like an if condition I can use in the author dataset or does any one kno another option to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a parameter to be required or not is not available through the usual SSRS interface. The easiest work around is to set the parameter to always be required and add a value to that parameter's dataset (such as `<Not Required>`.) Then conditionally set that to be the default value for the parameter when appropriate.

This can be accomplished in a sql statement:

```
SELECT
  field1
  field2
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  mycondition = whatever

UNION ALL
SELECT
   '<Not Required>',
   1
```

Comment: How do I add a value to the dataset without adding data to the sql data table itself. Since the values in the dropdown are coming from available values in a data table.